Does suspension because of low-quality contributions need moderators?
Is temporarily suspension because of low-quality contributions done automatically by the system or does it need moderators?
I hope the latter...

Furthermore, do any forms of suspension occur automatically? I haven't heard of any yet myself, but I'd certainly want to!

It needs moderators. Suspension always occurs after considerable thought and discussion between the moderators.
